# create new column Pandas df with str.contains gives: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen many almost similar questions, but I still didn't find the right answer.

My df has a column ['Name'], containing names of all kind of stores. I want to categorize these by giving, for example, a grocery store the label 'Supermarket' in a new column df['Type'].

I first did this:

```
df['Type'] = df['Naam'].str.contains('Albert')
```

This gives a True False series.

after that  I did this:

```
df['Type'] = df['Type'].replace({True: 'Supermarkt'})
```

That works, but is not very smart..... after writing an other line of str.contains for an other shop, obviously every value in ['Type'] became a Bool again....

Then I did this:

```
df['Type'] = (df['Naam'].str.contains('Albert'), 'Supermarkt')
```

My Idea was that I would be able to reuse this code, with an other part of a string over and over.

But.....

```
df['Type'] = (df['Naam'].str.contains('Albert'), 'Supermarkt')
```

gives an error:

`Length of values does not match length of index`. I think I understand what it means, but can't figure out why the first str.contains() gives a full series and this one gives an error....

So my question is: is there a way to alter `df['Type'] = (df['Naam'].str.contains('Albert'), 'Supermarkt')`, in a way that 1: True becomes 'Supermarkt' and all the False values stay in place or are replaced by something else?

Thanks in advance. Greetings Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create a selection
boolean_indexer = df['Naam'].str.contains('Albert')

# create your new column 
df.loc[boolean_indexer, 'Type'] = 'Supermarkt'
```